# Translation missing

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, js-translation, translation-dictionaries

This is my resulting html

```
<div data-ui-id="checkout-cart-validationmessages-message-error">
    The requested qty is not available
</div>
```

Probably generated by :

```
<div data-role="checkout-messages" class="messages" data-bind="visible: isVisible(), click: removeAll">
    <!-- ko foreach: messageContainer.getErrorMessages() -->
    <div role="alert" class="message message-error error">
        <div data-ui-id="checkout-cart-validationmessages-message-error" data-bind="text: $data"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The key is already present in my i18n translation file.

What is missing there for the translation to be applied ?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
data-bind="text: $data"
```

with:

```
data-bind="i18n: $data"
```

Comment: Tried it it's not working sadly :/